# Page title not updating? Drupal/PHP hook title

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to change my page title. To visit the page - [click here](https://www.workbooks.com/sales-performance-calculator).

This is written as a custom module within Drupal 7. The file is called wb_spc.module for this module code in JSFiddle, please [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/8xkbhse7/).

I've tried changing lines 51 and 59 but this won't change the h1 page title?

Please see a code snippet below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function wb_spc_menu() {
  $items = array();

  // Admin configuration group.
  $items['admin/config/wb_spc'] = array(
    'title' => 'Workbooks Self-Assessment CRM ROI Calculator',
    'description' => 'Administer WB CRM Requirements',
    'access arguments' => array('administer wb crm requirements'),
  );

  // Admin configuration - Settings.
  $items['admin/config/wb_spc/manage'] = array(
    'title' => 'Workbooks Self-Assessment CRM ROI Calculator Settings',
    'description' => 'Manage WB CRM Requirements settings and configurations.',
    'access arguments' => array('administer wb spc requirements'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('wb_spc_admin_settings_form'),
  );

  $items[variable_get('wb_spc_path')] = array(
    'title' => 'Workbooks Self-Assessment CRM ROI Calculator', 
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 
    'page arguments' => array('wb_spc_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  $items['wb_spc/test'] = array(
    'title' => 'TESTING - Workbooks Self-Assessment CRM ROI Calculator', 
    'page callback' => 'wb_spc_test', 
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  $items['wb_spc/results/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'WB Show PDF', 
    'page callback' => 'wb_spc_show_pdf', 
    'page arguments' => array(2),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Comment: What are the "lines 51 and 59"? We cannot see the line numbers from the code you pasted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the page (the one you see as a user), add this:

```
drupal_set_title('Page title goes here');
```

Change the `<h1>`, i believe the page title will be changed also if you do. If you want page title to be other than `<h1>` use the method `drupal_set_title('Page title goes here');`

To change it from only a certain page use:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'www.yourdomain.com/rest/of/url'){
    drupal_set_title('Page title goes here');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seeing as there is a title already present. Shouldn't I simply be able to change something rather than adding in another line?

Comment: Change the `<h1>`, i believe the page title will be changed also if you do. If you want page title to be other than `<h1>` use the method `drupal_set_title('Page title goes here');`

Comment: P.S. Your solution worked but it scares me as it seemed to be too easy! Where is the correct place to put this line? I put it on line 35 (above the hook_menu configuration). There is no <h1> to change as it pulls this from the title automatically.

Comment: Delete the line `drupal_set_title('Page title goes here');`. Now change the `<h1>`, and tell me what the page title is?

Comment: There is no <h1> within the .module or values.php please see the jsfiddle link I provided above. I can't edit the page anywhere else.

Comment: @Sam http://jsfiddle.net/8xkbhse7/1/ i think it's this one here. Change it and see what the page title is. Find my <---- arrow in the fiddle! or else try adding the lines with 'Workbooks Self-Assessment CRM ROI Calculator' and see if the page title changes. I think the H1 is generated somewhere in that code.

Comment: Deleted line and changed your suggested line (found arrow!) to "neverland" yet it still displayed "Workbooks Self-Assessment CRM ROI Calculator". I originally had hoped this would fix the issue. Will give you the answer as what your provided worked and you're exceptionally helpful.

Comment: Try adding the titles with 'Workbooks Self-Assessment CRM ROI Calculator' and see if the page title changes. I think the H1 is generated somewhere in that code. And you're welcome :)

Comment: Tried changing all of these to no avail (there were two). Weird. Your solution worked so will move on!

Comment: Your solution has had a strange side effect. When I login to my drupal admin panel, the title of each page is showing as the title I added within: "drupal_set_title('Page title goes here');"?

Comment: Try this: `if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'www.workbooks.com/sales-performance-calculator'){drupal_set_title('Page title goes here');}`